# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application shows COM object while debugging instead of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application class object

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, office-interop

I am using 64 bit machine I have some issues reagarding use of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application in my winform application.

**1.** Firstly my applications target platform is Any CPU and I have checked Prefer 32 bit checkbox.

**2.** Now I start debugging and i see the object of interop word application class then I can see the all information related to object (as shown in following screen shot 2).So I can see the count of documents attached with this object.
[image: Click here for screen shot 2]

**3.** After that I uncheck Prefer 32 bit checkbox

**4.** Then start debugging and I see the object of interop word application class then I cannot  see the all information related to object (as shown in following screen shot 4).
[image: Click here for screen shot 4]

Comment: So, your question is why is Office Interop working in your software when it is running in 32bit, but not when it is running in 64bit? AFAIK this is due to Interop depending on 1 specific version of Microsoft Office that needs to be installed on the PC. So if you want to use interop in a 64bit C# application then (IIRC) you'll either need the 64bit version of Microsoft Office installed on your PC, or you need to use late-binding (so that you're not depending on 1 specific version of Office).

Comment: How the debugger can map an interface (Application) back to a synthetic C# class (ApplicationClass) is fairly mysterious.  The simplest explanation is that you don't have the 64-bit version of Office installed.  So the debugger cannot find the type library that describes the interface.  That you can use a 32-bit Office program from a 64-bit program is COM magic.  The displayed info is also trimmed in the 32-bit flavor because you have the "Embed Interop Types" feature enabled, that embeds only the properties you actually use in your program.

Comment: by changing "Embed Interop Types" it worked. thanks